# Help with finding range and equation of a position vector (projectile)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, vectors

I'm given the position vector:

$$    r(t) = ht \hat\imath + t(v − 5mt) \hat\jmath$$

where $m$ = mass, $h$ = horizontal speed and $v$ = vertical speed.

Then the following data is given:

$$\begin{array}{lcc}
    \mbox{dist.} & 72 & 120 & 192 & 288 \\
    \mbox{height} & 68.4 & 110 & 166.4 & 230.4 \\
    \mbox{time} & t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4
\end{array}$$

The question is, Using the position vector, find a range for the missile in terms of $m,$ $v$ and $h.$

How would i go about doing this? Totally stumped as i've just started learning vectors. My only initial thought is to incorporate $vh/5m.$ Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use the math formats explained in http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/139123 next time. I made my best guess as to what you meant when I formatted this; check whether I got it right. I assumed your `i` and `j` were actually the basis vectors $\hat\imath$ and $\hat\jmath$ in the $x$ and $y$ directions.

Comment: What is the definition of the "range" of a missile? Is it the $x$-intercept ($x$ at the point where $y=0$)? If so, you've already guessed the answer to the question as written ("range in terms of $m$, $v$, and $h$"); do you need to understand _why_ that's the answer? Also, what is the purpose of all those data? The data would only come into play if we also want a literal numeric value of the range.

Comment: By the way, the only way "vectors" occur here is that the missile's position is modeled as a vector rather than just a pair of horizontal and vertical coordinates. The first step of the solution is to extract those coordinates, after which you never see vectors again. Not much calculus here, either; it seems straightforward algebra to me after that first step. Also, whoever posed this clearly has little physics background, as the role that $m$ plays here is nothing like the role mass would play in any realistic trajectory.

Comment: I've nominated this as a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1259103/139123; although this question was posted first, it did not yet have an upvoted or accepted answer at the time I found the duplication of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer to the literal question,
"find a range for the missile in terms of $m,$ $v$ and $h.$"
The table of values appears to be irrelevant to that question;
perhaps it is relevant to a follow-up question.

My recommendation is to solve the equation formally.
That is, forget what the book/instructor says $h$, $v$, and $m$ stand for,
because under the interpretation "$m$ is mass",
the formula makes no sense in any
reasonable interpretation of projectile motion according to the laws of physics.
If you ignore the "meaning" of $m$, however, the formula describes
a perfectly well-defined trajectory (position as a function of time)
that happens to follow a parabolic arc.

Assuming the "range" of the missile is its positive $x$-intercept, that is,
the horizontal coordinate at the point where the vertical coordinate is zero
(excluding the obvious point where *both* coordinates are zero),
then you want to find $h$ when $t(v-5mt) = 0$.

You can solve for $t$ in $t(v-5mt) = 0$, which gives two possible values of $t$.
Choose the value of $t$ that corresponds to the range of the missile
(the value $t=0$ is clearly not what you want),
and then find the value of the horizontal coordinate (which is $ht$)
at that value of $t$.

If you can follow that procedure, you'll see that you already guessed
the correct answer in the text of your question.

Comment: Cheers for the help! as a follow up question, how would i go about using the data points in the OP to make two equations involving m, h and v without time?

Comment: One thing you can do is set $x=ht$ and $y=t(v-5mt)$; from the first equation you get $t = \frac xh$; now substitute $\frac xh$ in place of $t$ in the second equation, so you are left with an equation giving $y$ as a function of $x$ (with parameters $h$, $v$, and $m$). I'm not sure if that's what you mean, but it's one way to approach the problem of determining $h$, $v$, and $m$ from the given table of data, which you can take as values of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Would that only give one final equation(y)? A friend of mine used this as a reasoning but i'm not sure how to carry out his approach:

r(t1) = 72(t1)i + 68.4(t1)j -
Hence:
h(t1) = 72,     
(t1)(v − 5m(t1)) = 68.4
You can combine these to eliminate t1. Do this for two other points to get three equations in h, v and m

Comment: What is $72(t_1)$? Is it "$72$ as a function of $t_1$", or is it $72$ multiplied by $t_1$? Neither of those seems useful in this context. Better would be to set $ht_1=72$, $t_1(v-5mt_1)=68.4,$ which imply that $\frac{72}{h}(v-5m\frac{72}{h})=68.4$. To continue this discussion, it would be better if you posted a new question with the formula, the data table, a clear statement of what kind of result you're looking for (something _not_ mentioning $h$, $m$, or $v$ any more, apparently), and your friend's solution attempt from your previous comment.