# projectile motion with mass, find the range

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

a missile has the position vector ***P***(t) = ht ***i*** + t(v − 5mt) ***j***.  where m is the mass (kg) of the missile, and h/v is the horizontal/vertical speed (respectively) the missile is launched with.

Using the position vector, find a range for the missile in terms of m, v and h.

looked at several links, (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_projectile, http://www.slideshare.net/hassaanbinjalil/vectors-projectile-motion (page 43)) both show different ways of showing the range but none include mass.  I tried working with SUVAT equations but again, no mass.  I've run out of ideas.

Comment: This question would probably better be asked there: http://physics.stackexchange.com/, since this is more a physics than mathematics question. To answer shortly, there is a mistake (except if you forgot to mention any other unity than mass (kg) and speed), since speed (v) cannot be compared to mass (kg) $\times$ time (s) in the formula $(v-5mt)$...

Comment: I think this is where a lot of my confusion is coming in as well, I'll chuck the question up there as well, thanks for your help! @Martigan

Comment: This same question was asked at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1258617/139123. I speculated then that the problem was posed by a math teacher with little physics background, because the interpretation of $m$ as "mass" in the given formula makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula in OP seems wrong.
The correct formula is
$$
\mathbf P= ht \mathbf i+t(v-\dfrac{1}{2}gt)\mathbf j
$$
and $m$ has no rule, since gravitational mass and inertial mass are the same: i.e. all bodies fall in the same way, with acceleration $g=9.8 m/s^2$

So, in your case, it seems that the term $5t$ is an approximation for $\dfrac{9.8}{2}t$

The $\mathbf j$ component (vertical) is $0$ when $t(v-5t)=0$ , i.e. $t=0$ (start point) and $t=\dfrac{v}{5}$, this last time is the time whan the projectile falls and substuting it in the $i$ component (horizontal), you have the range $x= h\dfrac{v}{5}$.

Comment: could you clarify on that last sentence? where did you get 5t^2?

also is this the *range* of the missile? @emilio-novati

Comment: @shalorsar:  by distributing out the last term in your equation.  As written, you get $-5mt^2 \bf{j}$

Comment: I have added the complete solution to my answer.

Comment: Another question was posted just hours earlier, using the same formula, so I think that insofar as the posted formula is "wrong", the error is down to the book or instructor that posed the problem, and is not an error on the part of the OP. My recommendation is to solve the problem formally, ignoring the stated "meaning" of the variables.